# Relay Modern- what is database.js and is it necessary?

Tags: react-native, graphql, relayjs, relay

In the Relay Modern example app `todo-modern` there is a file called database.js. Is this file necessary in all Relay Modern apps? If not, how do you define `{nodeInterface, nodeField}` without it? It seems to have all of these getter functions that I don't understand the point of.

I'm finding that there is not enough documentation or examples of Relay Modern. It is quite frustrating.

Comment: The file [`database.js`](https://github.com/relayjs/relay-examples/blob/master/todo-modern/data/database.js) is mocking data. Have a look at this tutorial for an in-depth step by step guide to Relay Modern: https://www.graph.cool/docs/tutorials/relay-modern-getting-started-woodito7ug/.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't clearly stated in the documentation, but schema.js and database.js are for the purposes of mocking a remote server service running GraphQL. I already have a PHP backend running a GraphQL server, so here's what I had to do:

1. Install the npm package [get-graphql-schema](https://github.com/graphcool/get-graphql-schema) globally.
2. Add an npm script to my package.json: `"generate-graphql": "get-graphql-schema http://0.0.0.0:8000/graphql > ./App/Data/schema.graphql"`. Obviously, change the local endpoint to your server's graphql endpoint, and change the output to where you want your schema to exist
3. Run `npm run generate-graphql` which generates the schema
4. Add an npm script to use the new schema to build necessary generated files: `"relay:build": "relay-compiler --src ./App --schema ./App/Data/schema.graphql"`. Again, change endpoints as necessary.
5. Run this new script. You should be good to go!